# Firebase Auth - GetTokenResult.getExpirationTimestamp throws ClassCastException internally

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get the expiration date of an "Id Token" of a Firebase user but whenever I call the method, it throws a `ClassCastException` instead of returning a value.

My configuration is:

- Android Studio 4.1 Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6858069, built on September 23, 2020
- Using Firebase Auth: `platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.0.0')`

Here's a sample code of the steps:

```java
// Please consider the case of an existing logged in user with a valid "Id Token"
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getIdToken(false).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
        GetTokenResult idTokenInstance = task.getResult();
        String idTokenString = idTokenInstance.getToken();
        // This line crashes
        long expiration = idTokenInstance.getExpirationTimestamp()
    }
});
```

Also the stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: br.com.muambator.android, PID: 2694
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application br.com.muambator.android.ui.application.MuambatorApplication: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4702)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:162)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1409)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
        at com.google.firebase.auth.GetTokenResult.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop@@19.0.0:18)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.GetTokenResult.getExpirationTimestamp(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop@@19.0.0:6)
        at br.com.muambator.android.model.User.isIdTokenExpired(User.java:56)
        at io.bode.social.AuthUtil.updateFirebaseIdToken(AuthUtil.java:90)
        at br.com.muambator.android.ui.application.MuambatorApplication.onCreate(MuambatorApplication.java:150)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4699)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:162) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1409) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
```

And a screenshot of the evaluation:
[image: Screen Shot 2020-11-19 at 18 30 23]

Comment: Try using,
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted this problem in the library's GitHub page and it's under investigation by the team:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2188#issue-746941283

There is a workaround which is to get the complete dictionary of information about the token and then extract the expiration timestamp from it, like so:

```java
GetTokenResult idToken = task.getResult();
// Expiration timestamp
long expiration = ((Double) idToken.getClaims().get("exp")).longValue()

// If you want to compare with the current time
// From `import java.util.Calendar;`
long now = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
boolean hasExpired = expiration < now;
```